# Why is it “objections to moving”, not “objections to move”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrasal-verbs, gerunds, syntactic-analysis

I got this sentence from the *Economist*:

> There are two primary objections to moving to the chained CPI.

My question is, why have they used *moving* instead of *move* after *objections to*?

Comment: I think this is General Reference because the question can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information. In fact you can find the answer here http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/verblist.htm in the table named "Verbs Followed by a Preposition and a Gerund".

Comment: @Carlo: that link is actually wrong in at least one case. It's "I detest speaking in public", and not "I detest to speak in public".

Comment: _Two primary objections to move to chained CPI._ may work in headlinese, with 'move' here as a noun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you need a noun to complete the phrasal verb *objecting to **XXX***.  That means you need a noun phrase there.  *Moving* as a gerund is a noun.  *Move* by itself is not one.

You seem to have been distracted into thinking that there is a *to*-infinitive involved here.  There is not.  That *to* is part of *object to*, not part of *to move*.

Comment: Precisely. Constituents are what's important, not words. If you interpret the boundaries of the constituents wrong, you get nowhere.

Comment: I don't believe there is any magic formula here with nouns or verbs. You can say "I aspire to greatness", but you have to say "I aspire to *paint* nudes". Similarly, you can say "I object to greatness", but you have to say "I object to *painting* nudes".

Comment: But three of these constructions are verb + preposition (+ ...) - where _to_ is the preposition, while one is verb + to-infinitive (+ ...), a catenation in which a totally different word, _to_, the infinitive marker, is used.

Comment: @PeterShor I don’t find that “I aspire to paint nudes” sits well with me. I would prefer that to be “I aspire to painting nudes” — *Two Gentleman from Verona* notwithstanding (“Wilt thou aspire to guide the heauenly Car.”).

Comment: @Edwin: That's true. What I'm trying to point out is that just because a verb takes "to + noun" doesn't mean that that it takes "to + gerund".

Comment: @tchrist: Compare *aspire to take* and *aspire to taking* in [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aspire+to+take%2Caspire+to+taking&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). You see that *aspire to take* is by far the preferred variant.

Comment: _Aspire_ is recognised as a verb catenating with (semantically sensible) to-infinitives ( http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/nonfiniteclauses.html - look for a forest of brackets), as well as a verb taking prepositional phrases starting with the other _to_. These may have an -ing form after the preposition. This is summed up reasonably well at http://www.englishforums.com/English/HowWordAspireCorrectly/lhpxd/post.htm ( but there is no way _to_ is a preposition in _She aspires to achieve greatness_).

Comment: There are articles on **catenation** at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs and on **'Verb + Preposition Combinations'** at   http://english-learners.com/2010/01/verb-preposition-combinations-2.html . An example of the latter: subject someone to (doing) something : She subjected her daughter to [taking] swimming lessons.  [_swimming_ not an '-ing form' here, whereas _taking_ is] There don't seem to be many verbs that both catenate with a to-infinitive and take a prepositional phrase with _to_. _Apply_ is one other: he applied to go / he applied to the board.

Answer (score -3):

Compare

- I have objections to eating horse meat.
- He has fantasies of painting nudes.
- She is possessed with eating cupcakes all day.
- I do love having briyani for dinner.

with

- I have objections to eat horse meat.
- He has fantasies to paint nudes.
- She is possessed to eat cupcakes all day.
- I do love to have briyani for dinner.

Let's elaborate on the stories.

> Jan: Mary, do you eat horse meat?
>   Mary: No. I have objections to eating horse meat.
>   Jan: Henry, do you have objections to the silly-pussy wishy-washy liberacci animal welfairy attitudes of Mary's, to eat horse meat?
>   Henry: I have objections, to eat horse eat. I have sufficient of such objections to let me eat horse meat.

There are two modes of speech here

- Use of a noun phrase due to the present continuous particle aka gerund, as subject of story
- Use of an infinitive verb phrase, as subject of story.

Occasionally both modes would result in the same message.

- I love drawing animals.
- I love to draw animals.

However,

1. I would like drawing animals.
2. I would like to draw animals.

sing different messages.

For an illustration, let us use the auxiliary verb {would} to encapsulatie the story in a generalised time domain,

```
I <TimeDomain>{would} {rest of predicate}
```

Where TimeDomain is an encapsulation of being either Past or Subjunctive.

The following encapsulates the story within a period/range of time in the past, where the action is not [punctiliar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punctiliar) (a point in time).

> As a child, I would like drawing animals whenever I felt like it. I would climb trees and rocks anytime there was daylight.

The following encapsulates a subjunctive domain, asserting a desire to execute a punctiliar event of starting an action, in subjunction to a condition or another action.

> Hmm... what would I like to do next? What should I do after we have sprayed graffiti? I would like to paint animals!

Comment: I don't understand this answer. *"I have objections to painting nudes,"* but *"I have aspirations to paint nudes."* Similarly, *"I object to painting nudes,"* but *"I aspire to paint nudes."* Basically, you just have to know which verb form goes with which noun/verb. As far as I can tell, there's no magic formula.

Comment: The 5th, 6th and 7th bulleted sentences are unacceptable: 'Your search - "objections to eat" - did not find any results.' "fantasies to paint" - 1 (once repeated) result. "possessed to eat" - 4 distinct relevant Google hits. 'Have objections to' takes an -ing form (perhaps with a completer) or noun group. 'Love' + 'having' and 'Love' +  'to have' are examples of _love_ catenating with an -ing form and a to-infinitive respectively.